# R Shiny selectizeInput server side not initializing correctly

Tags: r, widget, shiny, server-side, selectize.js

When trying to embed the selectize input widget in an Shiny application I ran into the following problem:

The item list isn't initialized with the complete list of items when using `server = TRUE`. Only after entering a character in the searchbox will the items appear. This is contrary to the behaviour when `server = FALSE`. In this case all items appear in the box initially (and this is the behaviour that I want). The reason that I want to use the `server = TRUE` option is that I want to be able to apply formatting to the items and this is not possible when generating the items client side. The example below reproduces the phenomenon with one selectize input using `server = TRUE` and the other with `server = FALSE`. In my opinion the behaviour should be the same in both cases.

Example app.R to reproduce the issue:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'cars1', server = TRUE, choices = rownames(mtcars))  
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'cars2', server = FALSE, choices = rownames(mtcars))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput('cars1', label = "server side", choices = NULL),
  selectizeInput('cars2', label = "client side", choices = NULL)  
  )

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is this a bug or am I using the widget incorrectly? I am running R version 3.1.3 and Shiny 0.11.1 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/823) in **shiny** v0.12.0 ([on CRAN now](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/shiny/)). The server side `selectizeInput()` will load the first 1000 options initially (or the first `n` options when `n < 1000`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the fix. Great work by the R studio guys!

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an option to set initialized values for selectize. Its in the `options` as `items`. You have to pass it an array of the values you want there, so you should be able to just pass it `rownames(mtcars)` and it should work. Though I've never tried it with more than one value so I'm not 100% positive.

So I believe the command in your case would be

```
selectizeInput('cars1', label= "server side", choices = NULL, options = list(items = rownames(mtcars))),
```

And then so on with the other lines. Alternatively, if that doesn't work try hardcoding the initial values in the items array. Not great I know, and I don't know how many initial values you have, but I do believe it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't solve the problem unfortunately. When I add this option the initial selectize dropdown menu is still empty. Futhermore I want to embed this in an application were the contents of the selectize widget is updated depending on the value of another widget (selectInput).

Comment: Great to see you got it! I was going to suggest 'selected', but I couldn't find exact documentation on it and I wasn't sure if it was exactly what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer of Colin I found a workaround that seems to work, although I still think that this is actually a Shiny bug. By first selecting all choices by adding the argument `selected = rowsnames(mtcars)` and after that calling `updateSelectizeInput()` again, selecting the first item, the item list is populated with all choices/items. This also works with `multiple = TRUE` (as I want to use it).

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'cars1', server = T, choices = rownames(mtcars), selected = rownames(mtcars))
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'cars1', server = FALSE, selected = rownames(mtcars)[1])
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'cars2', server = FALSE, choices = rownames(mtcars))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
   selectizeInput('cars1', label= "server side", choices = NULL, multiple = F),
  selectizeInput('cars2', label = "client side", choices = NULL)  
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```